# How to query based on max size of attribute in a JSON object array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I am trying to create a query based on a JSON body that contains an attribute in an array that is a float. This JSON object array can contain multiple indexes but I am having trouble getting the biggest attribute and the associated. How do I pull the correct array index based on a 'date' field?

I have tried doing a CROSS JOIN LATERAL statement that sorts in DESC order and limiting by 1 but this database has multiple rows that need to be queried on.
The JSON structure:

```
{
"identification":"123a",
"array": [
   {
     "type":"created",
     "num": 123.45
   },
   {
     "type":"delete",
     "num": 123.46
   }
   ]
}
```

So far, my query looks like:

```
SELECT col -> 'identification' AS Identify FROM tbl t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.col -> 'array') jae (array)
ORDER BY jae.array -> 'num' DESC
```

I want the result to be returned all in a JSON format including the 'identification' attribute. The biggest number for the 'num' attribute in the array, along with the other attributes in that object, should be returned with the identification. It kind of works but I am seeing the query return all the objects of the array. The result of the query should look like

```
{
"Identify":"123a"
   "array":{
      "type":"delete",
      "num": 123.46
}
}
```

The result should omit the 'created' object type and only return the attributes based on the max size of the 'num' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT json_build_object('Identify', t.col -> 'identification', 'array', x.elem)
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT a.elem
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(t.col -> 'array') a(elem)
   ORDER  BY a.elem -> 'num' DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) x;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=969ebe3828eb2056b6c18e170217b360)*

Returns `json`. You might want `jsonb` instead.

Comment: What does the alias a(elem) do here?

Comment: @JoshHale: Declares table and column alias. Useful for more complex cases, like for adding ordinality. For the simple case we could use short syntax, but I prefer to be explicit. `jsonb_array_elements()` (like some other json functions) provides its own result column name(s) - `value` in this case - which can be used unless declared otherwise.

Comment: Well TIL. Thanks